# Capturar error de argumento

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
public static void veureinfo(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{

      File origen = new File(filePath);


      if (origen.isFile()){
       System.out.println("Java VeureInfo " +origen.getAbsolutePath());
       System.out.println("INFORMACIÓ: Informació sobre el fitxer:");
       System.out.println("Nom del fitxer : "+origen.getName());
       System.out.println("Ruta : "+origen.getPath());
       System.out.println("Ruta Absoluta : "+origen.getAbsolutePath());
       System.out.println("Es pot escriure : "+origen.canWrite());
       System.out.println("Es pot lleguir : "+origen.canRead());
       System.out.println("Grandaria : "+origen.length()+(" bytes"));

      }else{

         System.out.println("directorio") ;
      }

   }


public static void main(String args[]) {


    try {
        veureinfo(args[0]);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println(error);
    }
}
}
```

La duda que tengo es, si dejo vació el espacio de los argumentos es decir si no pongo ninguno me salta error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at veureinfo.VeureInfo.main(VeureInfo.java:35)
>   C:\Users\Montse\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

¿Cómo puedo capturar este error?

Comment: ¿Capturarlo cómo? ¿quieres almacenar logs o algo similar?

Comment: Quiero que salga en pantalla por ejemplo:

Comment: 1- No has añadido ningún argumento.
2- No se encuentra nada por ese argumento.

Supuestamente la capura del argumento ya está.. pero no funciona.. T_T

Comment: Si no me equivoco el problema es que estas llamando a args y existe pero está vacío. Ocupas capturarlo por fuera. El try que estas utilizando solo te retornara si hay un error accediendo al elemento, no si accedes mal al arreglo.  Comprueba primero si `args` contiene algo y si no pues dile que lanze un error personalizado, todo antes de el try que utilizaste.

Comment: Hasta donde se no se pueden caputar errores donde no se manden argumentos a un método, porque no enviarlos no genera ningún error cachable, ¿En qué casos no estarías mandando un argumento a tu método donde te veas obligada a hacer esto que preguntas?

Comment: perdón pero no te entiendo. El tema es que tengo que hacer un programa que al final capture todos los errores que puedan pasar.

1- Que por ejemplo a alguien se le olvide poner un argumento.
2- Que el argumento buscado no exista ( Puede haberse equivocado en una letra por ejemplo)

Y ahora mismo cuando una de esas dos cosas pasan mi programa explota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto puede que ayude.

```
public class Pruebatry {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    if (args.length==0) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Error!! No hay nada!!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Pruebatry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Si paso el código");

    }
}

}
```

Si quisieras más comprobaciones solo tendrias que encadenarlas antes de comprobar tus argumentos.

---

**Actualizacion**
De esta manera no se congela.

```
public class Pruebatry {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    if (args.length==0) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Error!! No hay nada!!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("La liaste compadre!! Captura un argumento!");
            operacionQueUseScannerParaVolverAIntentarlo();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Si paso el código");

    }
}

}
```

En realidad es muy similar, solo elimine el logger y ejecuto las operaciones que yo quiera.

---

**MAS ACTUALIZADO**

Si no quieres mandar una excepción no es necesario que lo pongas(Para el caso de 0 argumentos) puesto que no quieres que se congele. Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
public class Pruebatry {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    if (args.length==0) {
            System.out.println("La liaste compadre!! Captura un argumento!");

    }else{
        System.out.println("Si paso el código");

    }
}
```

}

Para los siguientes casos que quieras comprobar solo encadena los ifelse y obtendrás tus validaciones conforme a tus requisitos.

Comment: Puedo capturarlos de otra forma estos errores o la única forma es de esta? Mi idea es que se capturasen con un simple System.out.printn... 
Es posible?

Comment: Un ejemplo de como lo quieres capturar?

Comment: Es decir el de los argumentos. Si no hay ningún argumento que ponga algo como: No has puesto nada. 

El otro cambiando err. por out ya estaría. 

Es decir cuando digo capturar, lo que digo es que necesito que el programa si falta algo me avise no que explote.

Comment: Hoo!!, ok. Edito.

Comment: crea uno nuevo, el que has hecho es otra forma de capturar es correcto. Solo que lo necesito saber de las dos formas. :********+

Comment: Gracias!!!Ahora si! Me encanta tener las dos formas de capturar! Mil gracias!! :********

Comment: @MontseMkd Ya esta actualizada la respuesta (Mil veces más)